# Delete Entry from jstree does not works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jstree

I have 2 jstree.
from 1st tree i am sending selectd nodes to 2nd tree.
on back button I am deleting entry of 2nd tree with its id but it doesnot works but it fetches all the selected records.
here is my code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <style>
            html { margin:0; padding:0; font-size:62.5%; }
            body {  font-size:14px; font-size:1.4em; }
            h1 { font-size:1.8em; }
            .demo { overflow:auto; border:1px solid silver; min-height:100px;min-width: 400px;float: left }
            .demo1 { overflow:auto; border:1px solid silver; min-height:100px;min-width: 400px; float: right}
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.min.css" />
    </head>

    <body><div id="frmt" class="demo"></div>
        <div id="frmt1" class="demo1"></div>
        <script>
            var arrayCollection = [ {"id": "animal", "parent": "#", "text": "Animals"}, {"id": "device", "parent": "#", "text": "Devices"}, {"id": "dog", "parent": "animal", "text": "Dogs"}, {"id": "lion", "parent": "animal", "text": "Lions"}, {"id": "mobile", "parent": "device", "text": "Mobile Phones"}, {"id": "lappy", "parent": "device", "text": "Laptops"}, {"id": "daburman", "parent": "dog", "text": "Dabur Man", "icon": "/"}] ;
            </script>
            <script>

        function refreshJSTree() {
                $('#frmt1').jstree(true).settings.core.data = arrayCollection;
                $('#frmt1').jstree(true).refresh();
            }
                </script>
                <script>

            function deleteNode() {
                console.log("Delete : "+$('#frmt1').jstree("get_checked"));
                arrayCollection = arrayCollection.pop($('#frmt1').jstree("get_checked"));/*
                        .filter(function(el) {
                            return el.id !==  $('#frmt1').jstree("get_checked");
                        });*/
                refreshJSTree();
            }

                </script> 
        <script>
            function callGraph() {
                var akn=$('#frmt').jstree("get_checked");
                var c = akn + "";
                var spl = c.split("!");
                var dt = "";
                var cnt = spl.length - 1;                
                arrayCollection=[];        
                var temp=[];
                console.log("SPL : "+spl);
                for(q=0;q<cnt;q++)
                {
                    if (spl[q].startsWith(","))
                    {
                        var xp=spl[q].split(",")[1];
                        if(xp.startsWith("OU") || spl[q].startsWith("DC"))
                        temp.push(xp);
                    }
                    else if(spl[q].startsWith("OU") || spl[q].startsWith("DC"))
                    {                        
                     temp.push(spl[q].split(",")[0]);
                 }
                }
                console.log("TEMP : "+temp);
                /*for(q=0;q<cnt;q++)
                {
                    var test=0;
                    for(m=0;m<temp.length;m++)
                    {
                        var textData=spl[q]+"";
                        console.log(temp[m]);
                        if(textData.Contains(temp[m]))
                            test=1;
                    }
                    if(test==0)
                    {
                        if (spl[q].startsWith(","))
                        arrayCollection.push(spl[q].split(",")[1]);
                    else
                        arrayCollection.push(spl[q].split(",")[0]);
                    }
                }*/
                for (q = 0; q < cnt; q++) {
                    if (spl[q].startsWith(","))
                        dt=/*spl[q].split(",")[1]//*/dt ={"id":spl[q].split(",")[1],"text":spl[q].split(",")[1]}
                    else
                        dt=/*spl[q].split(",")[0]//*/dt = {"id": spl[q].split(",")[0] ,"text": spl[q].split(",")[0] };
                    arrayCollection.push(dt);
                }
                refreshJSTree();
            }
        </script>  

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jstree.min.js"></script>
        <button onclick="callGraph()">>></button>
        <button onclick="deleteNode()"><<</button>


        <script>
            $('#html').jstree();
            $('#frmt').jstree({
                'core': {
                    'data':<%= session.getAttribute("PATH")%>
                },
                "checkbox": {
                    "whole_node": false,
                    "keep_selected_style": true,
                    "three_state": true,
                    "tie_selection": false
                }, "search": {
                    "fuzzy": true
                }, "plugins": ["checkbox", "search"]
            });
    $('#frmt1').jstree({
                'core': {
                    'data':[{"text":"DC TEST"}]
                        },
                "checkbox": {
                    "whole_node": false,
                    "keep_selected_style": true,
                    "three_state": true,
                    "tie_selection": false
                }, "search": {
                    "fuzzy": true
                }, "plugins": ["checkbox", "search"]
            });
            /*$('button').on('click', function () {
                a = $('#frmt').jstree("get_checked");
                callGraph(a);
                // window.location = "read.jsp?name="+a;
            });*/ 
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide an array collection with sample data?

Comment: arrayCollection = [
                    {"id": "animal", "parent": "#", "text": "Animals"},
                    {"id": "device", "parent": "#", "text": "Devices"},
                    {"id": "dog", "parent": "animal", "text": "Dogs"},
                    {"id": "lion", "parent": "animal", "text": "Lions"},
                    {"id": "mobile", "parent": "device", "text": "Mobile Phones"},
                    {"id": "lappy", "parent": "device", "text": "Laptops"},
                    {"id": "daburman", "parent": "dog", "text": "Dabur Man", "icon": "/"}]